# Is there an Android app that scans a device for vulnerability issues?

Tags: applications, security

Is there an application that scan the phone or the phone image searching for vulnerability issues?
In the internet there are several tools that make Network scanning, but I found nothing specific for Android.
Any ideas please comment, I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you connect your phone to WiFi, it will acquire IP address. So you will be able to scan it's network services for vulnerablities from your desktop PC with convient programs.

I like NMAP port scanner and ZenMAP shell for it.

Also it looks like guys are porting NMAP to Android. [Link 1](http://androidforums.com/i7500-all-things-root/52941-nmap-android.html), [Link 2](http://androidforums.com/android-applications/46499-nmap-android-cross-compile-arm.html)

Answer (score 4):

Aside from open ports that a network scanner would find, you may also be vulnerable to certain local exploits. The somewhat recently released [X-Ray app](http://www.xray.io/) is designed to check for a number of known vulnerabilities (though it is not capable of fixing them - you'd need an updated version of Android for that).

Answer (score 1):

Huge edit.

Almost all of the "one-click root" methods exploit a security hole; it's usually a privilege escalation exploit to get "temp root" as a first step. (From there the scripts will go on to make /system read-write, allow writing to partitions that are normally read-only, etc., in order to keep root access across reboots.)

Obviously, if *you* can break the security of your phone, someone else can too.

TL;DR: If a root method exists for your phone that does not consist of **"unlock the bootloader and flash whatever you want"** -  you have a security vulnerability.

Comment: Root alone doesn't cause vulnerability.

Comment: Let me try rephrasing my answer.